# getting error : fetch errorSyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data in react ajax call

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

when i try to run ajax call in react js, i am getting error, `fetch errorSyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` here i have placed my ajax call, can anyone please look it in my code and help me to resolve this issue ?

```
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5', { 
      method: 'GET',
      mode: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => { return response.json(); })
      .then(responseData => { return responseData; })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("fetch error" + err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it is a get request you don't need headers and mode ;

```
fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5')
      .then(response => { return response.json(); })
      .then(responseData => { console.log( responseData ) })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("fetch error" + err);
    });
```

Comment: and if it says bloacked by cors try adding this in front of your url `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5`

Comment: You saved my day :) https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ you are genius, yes it is issue of CORS, it is working now

Answer (score 2):

This is because of`mode: "no-cors"` . As including that gave you empty html response. Comment or remove that line and you are good to go. The no cors option made it stuck at HTTP option method only.